# Send a variable into a void pointer, or a void pointer reference in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, boost, reference, void-pointers

I'm attempting map `boost::functions`. So I can call them by a string name, with input and output parameters.

Example:

```
 MyFuncs::CallFunc("MyClass::TestFunc", void* input, void* output);
```

I would like to create the input and output variables, and send a their pointers to `MyFuncs::CallFunc()` to be handled.

I can send a `(void* input)` pointer into the function, and extract it's value to int, string etc.

I cannot send a `(void* output)` that allocates it's own space to receive a value.   I must create a `new type(var)` inside the called function, or the variable will got out of scope once the function returns.

**MyFuncs.h**

```
//MyFuncs.h
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <map>

class MyFuncs
{
public:

    static std::map<std::string, boost::function<void (void*, void*&)> > myfuncs;

    template<class T>
    static void RegisterFunc(const std::string& name, void (T::*func) (void*, void*&), T* instance)
    {
        myfuncs[name] = boost::bind(func, instance, _1, _2);
    }

    static void CallFunc(const std::string& name, void* input, void*& output)
    {
        myfuncs[name](input, output);
    }
};

std::map<std::string, boost::function<void (void*, void*&)> > MyFuncs::myfuncs;
```

**MyClass.h**

```
//MyClass.h 
#include "MyFuncs.h"

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass()
    {
        MyFuncs::RegisterFunc("MyClass::GetNumber",  &MyClass::GetNumber,  this);
        MyFuncs::RegisterFunc("MyClass::GetString",  &MyClass::GetString,  this);
        MyFuncs::RegisterFunc("MyClass::EditNumber", &MyClass::EditNumber, this);
        MyFuncs::RegisterFunc("MyClass::EditString", &MyClass::EditString, this);
    }

    void GetNumber(void* input, void*& output)
    {
        int var = 1234;
        output = static_cast<void*>(new int(var));             //WORKS, var eats memory
        //output = static_cast<void*>(&var);                   //ERROR, var goes out of scope
    }

    void GetString(void* input, void*& output)
    {
        std::string var = "Get test";
        output = static_cast<void*>(new std::string(var));     //WORKS, var eats memory
        //output = static_cast<void*>(&var);                   //ERROR, var goes out of scope
    }

    void EditNumber(void* input, void*& output)
    {
        int var = *static_cast<int*>(input);                   //WORKS, var gets 4321 OK
        output = static_cast<void*>(new int(var));             //WORKS, var eats memory
        //output = static_cast<void*>(&var);                   //ERROR, var goes out of scope
    }

    void EditString(void* input, void*& output)
    {
        std::string var = *static_cast<std::string*>(input);   //WORKS, var gets "Edit test" OK
        output = static_cast<void*>(new std::string(var));     //WORKS, var eats memory
        //output = static_cast<void*>(&var);                   //ERROR, var goes out of scope
    }
};
```

**MyApp.cpp**

```
//MyApp.cpp 
#include "MyClass.h"

void main()
{
    MyClass myclass;

    void* in;
    void* out;

    MyFuncs::CallFunc("MyClass::GetNumber", NULL, out);  //atempting to fill the variable
    int getNumOut = *static_cast<int*>(out);
    printf("MyClass::GetNumber = %d \n", getNumOut);

    MyFuncs::CallFunc("MyClass::GetString", NULL, out);  //atempting to fill the variable
    std::string getStrOut = *static_cast<std::string*>(out);
    printf("MyClass::GetString = %s \n", getStrOut.c_str());

    int editNum = 4321;
    in = static_cast<void*>(&editNum);
    MyFuncs::CallFunc("MyClass::EditNumber", in, out);  //atempting to fill the variable
    int editNumOut = *static_cast<int*>(out);
    printf("MyClass::EditNumber = %d \n", editNumOut);

    std::string editStr = "Edit test";
    in = static_cast<void*>(&editStr);
    MyFuncs::CallFunc("MyClass::EditString", in, out);  //atempting to fill the variable
    std::string editStrOut = *static_cast<std::string*>(out);
    printf("MyClass::EditString = %s \n", editStrOut.c_str());

    getchar(); //wait for close
}
```

Comment: In C++17, you will want to explore the use of [`std::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) rather than `void*`. You can use the Boost version before C++17 officially rolls out

Comment: @WhiZTiM Thank you for the fast reply..   researching now.

Comment: Opps.  I'm still at c++98 due to some cross-platform specifics. Also why I'm still using boost here.  std::any won't be available to me yet.

Comment: What about using the Boost version, [**`Boost.Any`**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/any.html). It should work well with C++98. Since its been in Boost since 2001 or so...

Comment: I just read your updated comment about boost supplying std equivalent to std::any.   researching now.  Thank you much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**
Without using static_cast or extra boost functions, I was able to use pure C++.

`*(int*)output = var;` and `*(std::string*)output = var;` seem to do the trick.



**MyFuncs.h**

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <map>

class MyFuncs
{
public:

    //A list of function names linked to boost::functions.
    static std::map<std::string, boost::function<void (void*, void*)> > myfuncs;


    //Register a class function by name.       MyFuncs::RegisterFunc("MyClass::Test", &MyClass::Test, instance);
    template<class T>
    static void RegisterFunc(const std::string& name, void (T::*func) (void*, void*), T* instance)
    {
        myfuncs[name] = boost::bind(func, instance, _1, _2);
    }


    //Call functions by name, with input and output.       MyFunct::CallFunc("MyClass::Test", input, output);
    static void CallFunc(const std::string& name, void* input, void* output)
    {
        myfuncs[name](input, output);
    }
};

std::map<std::string, boost::function<void (void*, void*)> > MyFuncs::myfuncs;
```

**MyClass.h**

```
#include "MyFuncs.h"

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass()
    {
        MyFuncs::RegisterFunc("MyClass::GetNumber",  &MyClass::GetNumber,  this);
        MyFuncs::RegisterFunc("MyClass::GetString",  &MyClass::GetString,  this);
        MyFuncs::RegisterFunc("MyClass::EditNumber", &MyClass::EditNumber, this);
        MyFuncs::RegisterFunc("MyClass::EditString", &MyClass::EditString, this);
    }

    void GetNumber(void* input, void* output)
    {
        int var = 1234;
        *(int*)output = var;
    }

    void GetString(void* input, void* output)
    {
        std::string var = "Get test";
        *(std::string*)output = var;
    }

    void EditNumber(void* input, void* output)
    {
        int in = *(int*)input; //4321
        int out = in - 4320;   //result is 1;
        *(int*)output = out;
    }

    void EditString(void* input, void* output)
    {
        std::string in = *(std::string*)input; //"Edit Test"
        std::string out = in += " (edited)";   //result is "Edit test (edited)"
        *(std::string*)output = out;
    }
};
```

**MyApp.cpp**

```
#include "MyClass.h"

void main()
{
    MyClass myclass;

    int getNum;
    MyFuncs::CallFunc("MyClass::GetNumber", NULL, &getNum);
    printf("MyClass::GetNumber = %d \n", getNum);

    std::string getStr;
    MyFuncs::CallFunc("MyClass::GetString", NULL, &getStr);
    printf("MyClass::GetString = %s \n", getStr.c_str());

    int editNumIn = 4321;
    int editNumOut;
    MyFuncs::CallFunc("MyClass::EditNumber", &editNumIn, &editNumOut);
    printf("MyClass::EditNumber = %d \n", editNumOut);

    std::string editStrIn = "Edit test";
    std::string editStrOut;
    MyFuncs::CallFunc("MyClass::EditString", &editStrIn, &editStrOut);
    printf("MyClass::EditString = %s \n", editStrOut.c_str());

    getchar(); //wait for close
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`void* out` is declared inside `main`. For `out` to be valid, it should point to something whose lifetime is atleast that of `main`. Since you have not declared data members of type `int` and `string` inside your class `MyClass` which can be returned via `out`, so you need to allocate the memory.

Suppose you declared data member `int var;` in class `MyClass` then GetNumber would look like:

```
class MyClass
{
    private:
             int var;

    public:
    MyClass()
    {
        //Register function
        var = 10;  
    }

    void GetNumber(void* input, void*& output)
    {
        //int var = 1234;  //<-- instead of using local "var", now use MyClass::var i.e this->var
        output = static_cast<void*>(&(this->var));
    }
};
```

Comment: This could work, but if for some chance I get into multiple threads, it might blow up. I'd like to create the output variable outside of the class i'm calling.

Comment: @aquawicket: Then in that case you can simply do `int out_int; void *out = (void*)&out_int;` and `GetNumber(void* input, void *output) { *output = what_ever_int_value_you_like;`}

Comment: `GetNumber(void* input, void* output){ int num = 69; *output = num; }`    *output is an illegal indirection  no matter what I assign to it.

Comment: Does `out` point to something **before** calling `GetNumber`?

Comment: `int finalout = 13579;  void* out = (void*)finalout;  MyFuncs::CallFunc("MyClass::GetNumber", NULL, out);`        illegal indirection, even if *output = NULL; inside the function.

Comment: I'll give a break tonight.. The "epiphany" will happen tomorrow.  Thanks for the help.